# Flash and run a .hex file on a different Microcontroller with bigger flash from the same Cortex family

Tags: stm32, cortex-m3, hex-file

Is it possible to flash and run a compiled code (.hex-file) for a specific Microcontroller (for example STM32F205RC) on a Microcontroller from the same family with bigger flash-memory and RAM (without creating a new compiled version.)?

Example:
.hex for STM32F205RC (128K flash memory and 64K RAM) on STM32F205RE (512K flash memory and 128K RAM)

(it is obvious that the larger memories is not used)

Comment: Are you sure is only difference between two MCU is a size of programm memory? You need to compare datasheets ?

Comment: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f205rc.pdf Page 167

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datasheet says the MCUs are fully compatible, only memory size is different. The compiler should only use different linker script to change the RAM and Flash memory sizes. The compiled binaries should be identical, and you can also verify this.